# Rails: how can I write this so it won't fail if it returns nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm just not sure how best to write it. Cheers!

```
def get_prices(c)
  @print_prices = Billing.where(:name => c).first.attributes.select{ |i| i.match(/^print_/) }
end
```

Comment: What behavior do you want when the query returns no results?

Comment: Just for it not to fail, initially. I guess I could point it to a `:name` that I know exists should the `:name` in `c` not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
def get_prices(c)
  billings = Billing.where(:name => c)
  @print_prices = billings.first.attributes.select{ |i| i.match(/^print_/) } unless billings.empty?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you should store the return value of `Billing.where(:name => c).first` and test it.